# select all columns with one column has different value

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table,some records have all column values are the same, except one. I need write a query to get those records. what's the best way to do it? the table is like this:

```
 colA  colB colC
   a     b    c
   a     b    d
   a     b    e
```

What's the best way to get all records with all the columns? Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: is one or more values different ok, or must it be exactly one value different?

Comment: Thanks for adding an example of the input (the table). Still not clear on the wanted output. Can you post an example of what you want the output to be?

Comment: Is it always the same column that is different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you know that column3 will always be different, to get the rows that have more than one value:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table t
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING COUNT(distinct col3) > 1
```

If you need all the values in the three columns, then you can join this back to the original table:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t join
     (SELECT Col1, Col2
      FROM Table t
      GROUP BY Col1, Col2
      HAVING COUNT(distinct col3) > 1
     ) cols
     on t.col1 = cols.col1 and t.col2 = cols.col2
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(distinct col3) > 1` perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Just select those rows that have the different values:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM myTable
WHERE colWanted != knownValue
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please post examples of the data in the table and the wanted output.

Comment: Hi Oded, thank you for your help. Actually I need get all columns. The table is like this:     colA colB colC

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This will give you Col1, Col2 that have unique data.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Leasure. However, I need all columns with or without unique data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming col3 has the difs

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

OR TO SHOW ALL 3 COLS

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
HAVING COUNT(Col3) > 1
```